# RH Security Advisory how to interpret

Tags: rhel

I'm on RHEL 7:

```
[root@localhost ~]# cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.9 (Maipo)
```

Since I have yum-plugin-security installed I'm looking for security related patches with severity =important. As per the output there's one available.

```
[root@localhost ~]# yum updateinfo --sec-severity Important
Loaded plugins: product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
Updates Information Summary: updates
    1 Important Security notice(s)
updateinfo summary done
```

If I look further I get details such as the RHSA and CVE:

```
 [root@localhost ~]# yum updateinfo info --sec-severity Important
    Loaded plugins: product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
    
    ===============================================================================
      Important: freetype security update
    ===============================================================================
      Update ID : RHSA-2020:4907
        Release : 0
           Type : security
         Status : final
         Issued : 2020-11-04 09:39:15 UTC
           Bugs : 1890210 - CVE-2020-15999 freetype: Heap-based buffer overflow due to integer truncation in Load_SBit_Png
           CVEs : CVE-2020-15999
    Description : FreeType is a free, high-quality, portable font engine that can
                : open and manage font files. FreeType loads, hints,
                : and renders individual glyphs efficiently.
                :
                : Security Fix(es):
                :
                : * freetype: Heap-based buffer overflow due to
                :   integer truncation in Load_SBit_Png
                :   (CVE-2020-15999)
                :
                : For more details about the security issue(s),
                : including the impact, a CVSS score,
                : acknowledgments, and other related information,
                : refer to the CVE page(s) listed in the References
                : section.
       Severity : Important
    updateinfo info done
```

[Looking at inux  RHSA-2020:4907](https://access.redhat.com/errata/RHSA-2020:4907) --> Updates Packages I can see the packages that contain the fix:

[image]

When I check the current version and compare against the one that would be installed in case of an update I can see that the current version is `freetype-2.8-14.el7.x86_64` and the to be installed would be the package version that contains the patch Package `freetype.x86_64 0:2.8-14.el7_9.1` will be an update:

[image]

But I have few questions.

1. Why is the RedHat Security Advisory showing other rpm packages under Updated Packages (please see the ones mark with red question mark). I don't have the freetype-debuginfo, freetype-devel, freetype-demos packages installed. Would I have to have all the listed packages under my OS version and arch in the RHSA be on the same level ??

[image]

2. If I install the advisory I don't see any of the above (point 1) mentioned packages being installed / updated:

[image]

Could anyone please provide an explanation ?

Thank you !

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and use code formatting instead.

Answer (score 6):

The other packages are part of the same advisory, but you only need to upgrade them if they are already installed. The `debuginfo` packages provide debugging information, which is typically only needed if you are investigating a crash in Freetype, or developing with the library; the `demos` package contains demonstration tools, and the `devel` packages contain development files which are only needed to build programs using Freetype.

```
yum update --advisory RHSA-2020:4907
```

will do the right thing for you: it will upgrade any packages which need to be upgraded, without installing anything extra you don’t need.

Comment: Thank you for your help. So would it be safe to assume, that if I would have the other packages installed, would `yum update --advisory RHSA-2020:4907` automatically "detect" and update them to the "fixed" version ? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, it would automatically upgrade them.

Comment: Stephen, allow me to ask you one more. As I know the `yum-plugin-security` will not do any good for CentOS since the metadata is missing in repo's. But can I use the very same RH Secvurity Advisories to cross check the package versions to verify whether my CentOS system is patched? Or are the packages provided with CentOS different from a naming / verisoning convention than the one provided by RedHat? Thank you in advance.

Comment: The versions are the same. The announcement identifiers are the same too, and you can also find details there, in [CESA-2020:4907](https://lists.centos.org/pipermail/centos-cr-announce/2020-November/012870.html).